# how to fix the expo axios error -404 react native

Tags: react-native

expo axios error -404

axios.post(`http://myip:19000/auth/login`) Even in the postman, get works fine at 200, but nothing else. The app displays the following error

code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

```js
 axios
      .post(`http://myip:19000/auth/login`, {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value,
      })
```

Comment: Share a successful request from Postman. Should the body be in json format?

Comment: 404 means Page Not Found, i guess your URL i wrong